# Stratified cross validation with Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, cross-validation

My goal is to make binary classification, using neural network.
The problem is that dataset is unbalanced, I have 90% of class 1 and 10 of class 0.
To deal with it I want to use Stratified cross-validation.

The problem that is I am working with Pytorch, I can't find any example and documentation doesn't provide it, and I'm student, quite new for neural networks.

Can anybody help?
Thank you!

Comment: I haven't used stratified CV before. But as I see it, this is not tied directly to PyTorch. To me, it seems more like a general data processing topic. So some general examples without invoking PyTorch code should be just as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to do you stratified splits before passing your data to Pytorch `Dataset` and `DataLoader`. That lets you avoid having to port all your code to skorch, which can break compatibility with some cluster computing frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [skorch](https://github.com/dnouri/skorch). It's a scikit-learn compatible neural network library that wraps PyTorch. It has a function [CVSplit](https://skorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/dataset.html?highlight=fold#cvsplit) for cross validation or you can use sklearn.
From the docs:

```
net = NeuralNetClassifier(
   module=MyModule,
   train_split=None,
)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
y_pred = cross_val_predict(net, X, y, cv=5)
```